# Como marcar um evento no datepicker?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho esse código em javascript:

```
 $(function() {
      $("#calendario").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        ;
        monthNamesShort: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
      });
    });


<div id="calendario"> </div>
```

E apenas a `div` acima para chamar o calendário.

Como faço para cadastrar um valor no `datepicker`? Lembrando que tem que ser administrável, ou seja, possa cadastrar mais que 1.

Comment: Lucas qual datapicker é este ? do bootstrap ou do jqueryui?

Comment: @Highlander, seria o do jqueryui, porém tenho várias datas para cadastrar no mês, ou seja, vários eventos.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, primeira coisa, retire o ponto e vírgula causando erro de syntax [Linha 12].

Agora vamos as suas dúvidas:

**Como faço para cadastrar um valor no datepicker?**

Quando você fala em cadastro fica meio amplo, pode ser duas coisas ao meu ver.

1 - Setar um valor Default:

```
$("#calendario").datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2015" );
```

2 - Pegar um valor selecionado:

```
onSelect: function() {
  var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // pega valor selecionado
  console.log(dateAsObject);
}
```

Exemplo funcionando no: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/j7o0ra00/1/)

Mas se você deseja que seja selecionado no mesmo campo várias datas exemplo `25/12/2015,26/12/2015` etc...
Você tera que utilizar um Plugin por que isto não é suportado no jQueryUI datepicker ;(

Um plugin que você pode utilizar é: [MultDatepicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Na verdade é isso mesmo, preciso de várias datas.

Comment: Um amigo disse que é possível, porém complicado. 
Mas tentei de várias formas e não consegui, a data de hoje por exemplo, ele aplica uma formatação.

Comment: @LucasHenriqueDutra Então siga a solução do plugin MultDatepicker, se o seu amigo disse que é possível seria interessante pedir que ele responda a sua pergunta por que poderia ajudar pessoas futuramente, eu por  experiência digo que não tem como fazer, mas sempre existem exceções;